# How do I get up and running in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with TypeScript and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I thought I was smarter than this, but evidently I'm not. I'm a many-year veteran of software development. I used to work as an engineer at Google. I write TypeScript at work every day.

All I wanted to do was convert my [existing AngularJS website](http://www.jeffreygetzin.com) into a website that uses TypeScript instead of what I currently have, which is plain JavaScript with the Google Closure Compiler. And I want to be able to use Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition to do the editing, type-checking, etc. Ideally, I'd like to use ASP.NET WebForms to generate the HTML files dynamiclaly so I can do a few clever things server-side, but I'm not wed to the idea.

I have tried many different tutorials, including:

1. generator-angular-typescript-gulp
2. TypeScript, AngularJS, Gulp and Bower in Visual Studio 2015
3. Building AngularJS application with TypeScript and Visual Studio Code
4. Setting up TypeScript and AngularJs in Visual Studio 2013
5. Building Web applications with TypeScript and AngularJS in Visual Studio 2015

But none of these have gotten me what I needed, which was the following:

1. Out of the box, build an application without error. Some tutorials have failed because they couldn't handle the \ vs / issue of Windows. Others, complain that I don't have git installed (even though I do). Others have been written for what seem to be obsolete versions of NPM and/or Gulp packages and fail when followed verbatim.
2. Said application must be structured in a reasonably-realistic manner that will scale. Many walk-throughs seemed to be hacked-together examples that don't really show you best practices.
3. Said application must use TypeScript modules so that I can break my application into multiple, reusable components. Ideally, I'll be able to compile them together into a single output js file, but my attempts here have been disastrous.
4. Said application must be editable with Visual Studio, with the fewest number of "extra steps" required to work with the thing. An ideal situation would be to just have the darn thing built by Visual Studio, but I'm perfectly fine with typing in an npm or gulp command or three.
5. Said application should use relatively modern versions of the TypeScript and AngularJS 1.x (I'm not ready for AngularJS 2.0 yet).

So, here I am humbling myself, asking the cognoscenti how to do what I think should have been trivially easy to do.

Can you either point me to a *good* tutorial that actually *works* and provides the aspects I need, or else give me some decent step-by-step instructions?

You may assume moderate familiarity on my part with Visual Studio, AngularJS, NPM, NuGet, and TypeScript. You may also assume fledgling familiarity with Gulp, Grunt, and Yeoman. Finally, you may assume that I've used JSPM, but that I've used it with a cartoon-like question mark suspended over my head.

I've been trying, off and on again, for *months* to get this to work. I won't claim to be a genius, but I'm definitely not stupid. It seems to me that this ought to be easy, yet it's confounded me at every turn. Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope!

```
Jeff
```

P.S. This proliferation of package managers, created I'm sure with the best of intentions, reminds me of [this classic cartoon](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: If anything, this was an entertaining read. If no replies are here after a day or two, I'll probably write a solution that has it all encompassing.

Comment: That would be awesome to the power of marvelous times infinity. Thank you!

Comment: Your frustration isn't a testament to your knowledge or ability to get stuff done btw. Modern web dev is unnecessarily difficult, and even more so putting it together with Visual Studio is not that intuitive at all. I feel your frustration times 10.

Comment: Two days and no love from the crowd. Are you still willing to write up a solution? Honestly, I'm about to give up otherwise and consider the problem theoretically solvable yet intractable.

Comment: Yeah I still want to but time hasn't been in my favor.

Comment: I find the lack of responses to this question to be telling. Most computer questions like this get a very healthy response. I suspect that this problem really _is_ intractable and that it's extraordinarily difficult to get these technologies to place nicely together.

Comment: I think the larger issue is "ain't no one got time for that". Honestly, anything beyond linking to an existing solution will require a fair amount of work on an answerer's behalf, and honestly, "ain't no one got time for that". I wish I did though.

Comment: FYI, I finally got it working. It's an ugly solution, but I'll share it when I get some spare time.